# LOR from employer sent from unofficial email id as using official e-mail id is against the company policy

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, recommendation-letter

My senior is ready to write a LOR for me, but cannot use a company letterhead or official email id as it is against the company policy.

Company policy states use of official email id and letterhead for personal purpose is not allowed.

In that case if the senior uploads recommendation from personal email id will that be alright?

Comment: Is writing a LOR really a "personal purpose"? It doesn't seem very personal...

Comment: LOR expresses opinion and experience of the writer, not the position of the organisation they work for. In this regard, it is a personal communication from one person to a group addressee such as hiring committee or admissions team.

Comment: @Sursula-they- It's common in some places to have a company policy that the only thing the company will officially recognize is that "Yes, Luna Moon was employed by our company from date to date"; possibly including a job title. This is worthless as a recommendation letter for academic purposes, and the only alternative around the policy would be for a recommender to make it a personal recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will *probably* be fine, but they should explain the situation in the mail if possible. They can also ask for a confirmation from the person at their company email address. That is a bit of a fudge on the regulation, but probably not enough to cause problems.

If they have some visibility at the company website then that might help also.

But, universities realize that these sorts of things happen and are likely to be fine with it since you have no control.

The senior can also check with HR about the proper interpretation of the policy. It might be easier than you think. It might require that the senior show the letter to HR before sending it with "official" resources.

Comment: I did ask HR about it, they said it is next to impossible to open these URLs (even if they're from educational institutions) as they are blocked. 

However, I was hoping if unis are aware of such situations and not reject my application straightaway just because it's from a personal email.